# Need help aligning a div class to the middle

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I was wondering if theres a way to align a `div` element to the middle of the page using HTML (no css preferably).

The code is

```
<div class="colorlib-pricing" >
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2 text-center colorlib-heading animate-box">
                    <h2>Pricing</h2>
                    <p>We set our price with affordability in mind, we do not want to overcharge users for a good client, we find our clients' price reasonable and competitive.</p>
                </div>
            </div>
                <div class="col-md-3 text-center animate-box">
                    <div class="pricing">
                        <h2 class="pricing-heading">Wave Client</h2>
                        <div class="price"><sup class="currency">$</sup>19.99<small>LIFETIME</small></div>
                        <p>With permanent access, fast and frequent updates Wave Client will surely fulfill your cheating needs.</p>
                        <p><a href="https://waveclient.selly.store/product/49b4ed5e" class="btn btn-primary">Purchase Wave</a></p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Thanks alot in advance.

Comment: "(no css preferably)." Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you seem to be using bootstrap 3 you can change the following div `<div class="col-md-3 text-center animate-box">` to:

```
<div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4 text-center animate-box">
```

See working example below:

```html
  

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="colorlib-pricing">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2 text-center colorlib-heading animate-box">
        <h2>Pricing</h2>
        <p>We set our price with affordability in mind, we do not want to overcharge users for a good client, we find our clients' price reasonable and competitive.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4 text-center animate-box">
      <div class="pricing">
        <h2 class="pricing-heading">Wave Client</h2>
        <div class="price"><sup class="currency">$</sup>19.99<small>LIFETIME</small></div>
        <p>With permanent access, fast and frequent updates Wave Client will surely fulfill your cheating needs.</p>
        <p><a href="https://waveclient.selly.store/product/49b4ed5e" class="btn btn-primary">Purchase Wave</a></p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Another approach could also be to use the `center-block` class. However, you would also need to add a css style of `float: none;` to your div:

```
<div class="col-md-4 center-block text-center animate-box" style="float: none;">
```

See working example below:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="colorlib-pricing">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2 text-center colorlib-heading animate-box">
        <h2>Pricing</h2>
        <p>We set our price with affordability in mind, we do not want to overcharge users for a good client, we find our clients' price reasonable and competitive.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 center-block text-center animate-box" style="float: none;">
      <div class="pricing">
        <h2 class="pricing-heading">Wave Client</h2>
        <div class="price"><sup class="currency">$</sup>19.99<small>LIFETIME</small></div>
        <p>With permanent access, fast and frequent updates Wave Client will surely fulfill your cheating needs.</p>
        <p><a href="https://waveclient.selly.store/product/49b4ed5e" class="btn btn-primary">Purchase Wave</a></p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
<div style="width: 500px; margin: 0 auto;">I will be aligned in the center</div>
```

If you must have truly no CSS you can try

```
<div align="center">
  <div>I will be aligned in the center</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I tried adding it but that doesn't seem to align it

Comment: I don't think `<div>` is an element that supports the `align` attribute. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes

Answer (score -1):

you need to set child div margin auto.. 
**Note:** if you use display property then might its not work for some display properties - such as absolute, fixed etc.

```css
.parentDiv{width:100%; 
height:100px; 
background: #504f4f;
}

.childDiv{
margin:auto; 
width:60%; 
background: #85ffcc; 
height:100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="parentDiv" >
 <div class="childDiv" >      
 </div>
</div>
```